# Error while installing ROS on Ubuntu Oneiric

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello..
I get the following error after running the command:
**sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full**

Error is:
Reading package lists... Done ( I know this is not error)
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
**E: Unable to locate package ros-electric-desktop-full** *(the PROBLEM!!)*

Plz. help me out.
I don't get it how to re-index it to ROS.org server..isn't MAIN server sufficient?

Regards,
dbs

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12145/error-while-installing-ros-on-ubuntu-oneiric/) by [dbs12](https://answers.ros.org/users/1469/dbs12/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-11-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-11-29**:
Two questions (1) have you followed the installation instructions for sources.list? (2) Have you also run "sudo apt-get update"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe a little bit late: You have to add the ROS repository to the sources first. See: http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu#electric.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-Sources.Configure_your_Ubuntu_repositories

---

Originally posted by [Florian](https://answers.ros.org/users/1922/florian/) with karma: 16 on 2012-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0